# How to fetch results from multiple fluent NHibernate session factories?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using FluentNhibernate with Asp.net MVC.
For some reasons i have separate Databases with relationships across the DB.
I have multiple session factories for all of my DBs.

**Can I fetch the results using both session factories at once?**

Eg : [FirstDB].[FirstTable].[UID] is related to [SecondDB].[UserTable].[ID]
Thankful if explained with some example on How to do so!!

I followed this approach:

- Fetched [FirstDB].[FirstTable] results in one list.
- Fetched [SecondDB].[UserTable] results in another list.
- And then using linq or lamda expressins to get final result.

is this a good approach?

However, I would like to know whether I could write a query with joins for multiple session factoies? also the pros and cons of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly it is not possible to write one linq query (IQueryable) over multiple sessionfactories. The approach you posted is the only way i see. you could however optimise each query to filter unneeded records before using Linq to objects to form the endresult.

Comment: Can I achieve this using entity framework?
I am using SQLServer as backend.

Comment: it doesnt matter which LINQ provider you use. Just try to think of a sql-statement which you can execute over multiple databases (except some special sqlserver configurations using replication or something the like). You have to execute one sql per database and merge the results in memory